# Eager load google map tiles

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Nothing much to it.. just wonder whether there is a way to tell Google Maps to eagerly load tiles of a wider area than just the viewport so that when panning around, the user wouldn't have to wait for the new tiles to arrive.

I wanna prevent this:

[image]

Comment: Feel free to create a FR at: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=188853&template=787814 to allow caching more surrounding tiles. This way other developers can find and star it and the Maps API team can prioritize.

Comment: kaboom! https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/38110237

Comment: :) cheers, now consider clicking the ★ icon next to FR number to indicate you are interested in the Maps API team implementing this

Comment: Two stars already?? I'm expecting this to be shipped tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API already pre-fetches adjacent map tiles, albeit not a large amount.  There isn't a way to eagerly fetch beyond that.

Comment: Quite unfortunate